# Microchip studio include files based on specific configuration

Tags: configuration, project, microchip, atmelstudio

So, the idea is that based on the configuration you have chosen i want different set of files to be loaded into the project ( and be displayed ). For example :
I have a headers folder with two files, config1.h and config2.h. Src folder with config1.c, config2.c and main.c. When i choose config1 for the project is there a way to only show and use config1.h, config1.c and main.c.

I have scouted the internet and went trough all of the Atmel/microchip documentation, and going through all of the menus i could find.I am trying to avoid using #ifdef